# Error 000539 - Band_# not defined

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster-calculator, error-000539

I'm trying to do an NDVI analysis of a some World View 2 imagery. It seems no matter what if I enter the term Band_# for any of the 8 bands I get the same error. [image]

Comment: For reference this is the [**Error 000539 Help**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/92722/error-000539-band-not-defined).  The error you are getting seems to say that there is no variable called Band_8 defined so I think you need to look more closely at the syntax you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up figuring it out. There were two issues. One you have to use full path names. Even though it lets you drag and drop layers into the calculator that is functionally useless. Second the code "- band_#" is not correct. x:\directory\file.tif\band_# is what ended up working.